# Two divs inside parent, center according to rightmost div

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, step-navigation and form. I want to center the layout according to the form.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="step-navigation">(...)</div>
    <div class="form">(...)</div>
</div>
```

This is what I currently have:

[image: Image of current design]

This is what I want to achieve:
[image: Wanted design]

Comment: Can you add the CSS rules that apply to these classes?

Comment: How is the width of the 'form' element determined? And what do you want the layout to look like on narrow viewports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to building a layout like this is using CSS grids:

```css
/* Divide the main container into 3 columns, centring the middle one */
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: "steps page .";
}

/* Justify the "steps" to the right of the left column */
.stepsContainer {
  grid-area: steps;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: right;
}

.pageContainer {
  grid-area: page;
}

/* The styles below are just for demo purposes*/
.steps {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
}

.page {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="stepsContainer">
    <div class="steps"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="pageContainer">
    <div class="page"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```